# Set hotkey to move perpendicular to normal/slide on surface

Tags: transforms, normals

I'm basically just trying to avoid hitting <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> every time I want to move a vertex freely on a surface. Is there a way to set this to a single hotkey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what that key combination is supposed to do nor if it is supposed to be used in *Edit Mode* or *Object Mode* specifically, but go to the *User Preferences > Input* look for the relevant context under the *3D View* category, like *Global*, *Object Mode*, or *Mesh* etc.

Either add a new entr there using the *Add New* button at the bottom, or modify an existing.

Pick the relevant operator, I am guessing `transform.translate`, expand the settings bellow and adjust the available controls to your liking.

I supposed the *Constraint* and *Align with point Normal* are of particular interest to you.

[image: Keyboard Mappings]

Comment: Excellent. Using the XY constraint in combination with normal orientation seems to do the trick. ("Align with Point Normal" doesn't seem to do anything).

This basically just constrains the transform to the surface normal, allowing you to slide verts (approximately) over the surface. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update from a newbie: In Blender 2.80 the dialog is in 
Preferences > Keymap > 3D View > 3D View(Global) > Move* 
*note that are three "Move" functions. Edit that with the "G" key selected by default.

Although I'm searching a way to also move objects perpendicular to the viewport, this is useful for me.